# AND statement in sqflite flutter

Tags: sqlite, flutter, sqflite

I have been looking through the documentation of sqflite flutter package, I could not find how to use the AND statement in their documentation. Can anyone help me with this.
Below is the example of the sql query I would like to execute:
`` SELECT * FROM `table_name` WHERE `column_1` = "some_string" AND `column_2` = "another_string"; ``

Comment: the query seems correct can you share the code

Comment: My question is to execute the same query in the sqflite way.
As you can see from my code, I want to check for two columns but it only checks for one column
```var res = await client.query(
      'content',
      where: 'bookName = ?',
      whereArgs: [bookName, chapter],
);```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
List<Map> list = await database.rawQuery('SELECT * FROM Test WHERE column_1 = "some_string" AND column_2 = "another_string"');
```

Try this
This will generate list of map<column_name,value>